# Unable to set Edit text value in dynamic added edit text android on Onclick event

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I want to Add edit text according to array size . I successfully added  Dynamic edit text but problem is when i click on 0 index edit text i want to show value on 0 index edit text but it set on last index inflated edit text android.

```
 private void renderView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert inflater != null;
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        mCustomBinding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.custom_field,mBinding.conatiner,false);
        View view_cell = mCustomBinding.getRoot();
        mCustomBinding.tvCustomFieldHeader.setText("value"+j);
        mCustomBinding.edCustomField.setHint(">>>>>"+j);
        mCustomBinding.edCustomField.setTag(j);
        mCustomBinding.edCustomField.setId(j);
        mCustomBinding.edCustomField.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBinding.conatiner.addView(view_cell);
    }
} 

@Override public void onClick(View v) {
 if (v.getId()==mCustomBinding.edCustomField.getId()){ 
        mCustomBinding.edCustomField.setText("<>><><><><><"); }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mCustomBinding` holding the reference of last added.

**Change it as.**

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
 if (v instanceof EditText){     
        ((EditText)v).setText("<>><><><><><"); 
    }
}
```